# How to Change awesome icon on open / close status in jquery Simple Toggle sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to change this code to make the awesome icon,  changing it from close to open and vice-versa. I mean, when the sidebar is closed Then I had like to use the  [fa-align-justify \f039] awesome icon and when it is opened I had like to show the [fa-times \f00d]  awesome icon.

How to do that?

[Here is code](https://jsfiddle.net/marcoasg/1p2a3jjx/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <title>toggleBar</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script> 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- toggle-sidebar -->
    <div id="style-selector">
        <div class="style-toggle">
        </div>
        <div id="style-selector-container">      
            <div class="style-selector-wrapper">
                <h1>Content goes here!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">  

    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        if(jQuery('body').hasClass('home')){
            jQuery('#style-selector').animate({'right':'0px'},'slow');
            } else {
                jQuery('body').addClass('ss-open');
                jQuery('#style-selector').animate({'right':'-'+jQuery('#style-selector').width()+'px'},'slow');
            }
        });

        jQuery('#style-selector .style-toggle').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(jQuery('body').hasClass('ss-close')){
                jQuery('body').removeClass('ss-close');
                jQuery('body').addClass('ss-open');
            jQuery('#style-selector').animate({'right':'-'+jQuery('#style-selector').width()+'px'},'slow');
         }
         else if(jQuery('body').hasClass('ss-open')) {
             jQuery('body').removeClass('ss-open');
             jQuery('body').addClass('ss-close');
             jQuery('#style-selector').animate({'right':'0px'},'slow');
         }
         else {
             jQuery('body').addClass('ss-open');
             jQuery('#style-selector').animate({'right':'-'+jQuery('#style-selector').width()+'px'},'slow');
         }
     }
    );

</script>
<!-- end toggle sidebar -->

</body>
</html> 


/* STYLE.CSS Toggle Sidebar */

#style-selector {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 50px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0px 50px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    box-shadow: -3px 0px 50px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 280px; 
}

#style-selector .style-toggle {
    width: 52px;
    height: 56px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    float: left;
    margin-left: -52px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    top: 100px;
}

#style-selector .style-toggle::before {
    color: #f05254;
    content: "\f07a";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: lighter !important;
    line-height: 56px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#style-selector .style-toggle:hover:before {
    color: #06a0b0;
}

#style-selector-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/1p2a3jjx/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `content: "\f00d";` which will show `x` when the class `ss-close` is active https://jsfiddle.net/1p2a3jjx/2/

```
.ss-close #style-selector .style-toggle:before{
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

Comment: Hi Awsme Sandy.

Comment: Hi @Krsna any question?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  A Simple, direct  and beautiful solution! Code is Poetry.

Comment: @Krsna Thanks , please dont forget to upvote it and mark it as helpful